# Worker threads and MFC controls

Tags: c++, mfc, controls, worker

I'm aware of the fact that MFC GUI controls are not accessible directly from a worker thread, but for example, they getting by passing to this thread a pointer to the object instance that owns the controls. My problem is, that I'm really sure about how it goes when I'm calling functions within the scope of the worker thread, which needs to access MFC controls. Please consider the following code:

```
//header: 
class CMyDlg  : public CDialog
{
  ...
  ...
  ...
  afx_msg void OnButtonControl();
  static UNIT ControlThread(LPVOID pParam);
  bool ValidateEditControl();
}

//cpp
void CMyDlg::OnButtonControl()
    {
      CString Text = "Hello";
      GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT_HELLO)->SetWindowText(Text);
      m_hControlThread = AxtBeginThread(ControlThread, this);

    }

    UINT CMyDlg::ControlThread(LPVOID pParam)
    {
      CMyDlg *dlg = (CMyDlg*) pParam;
      CString Text = "Hello";
      while(SomethingIsTrue) {
        bool Ret = dlg->ValidateEditControl();
        if (!Ret) //Someone changed ControlEntry -> change it back
          dlg->GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT_HELLO)->SetWindowText(Text);
      }
      AfxEndThread(0);
    } 

    bool CMyDlg::ValidateEditControl()
    {
      CString Text;
      this->GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT_HELLO)->GetWindowText(Text); // do I need the "this" pointer here, or for general how do I access my MFC control at this point?
      if (Text == "Hello")
        return true;
      else
        return false;
    }
```

What is the best way to this?

Thank you in advance
best Greg

Comment: Your code will not compile. The first reason is that the ControlThread function must be declared as static. Correcting that will lead to other errors, so the premise of your question is off.

Comment: If `ControlThread` is declared static then you will also need to change `ValidateEditControl()` to `dlg->ValidateEditControl()` and `this->GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT_HELLO)` to `GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT_HELLO)` because `ValidateEditControl` is a member funtion and therefore `this` is already implied. It definitely sounds as though there is some confusion around the whole `static vs member` issue...

Comment: Thank you for the answers and I apologize for the incompleteness. Just edited my post.

Comment: Bad things can (will?) happen if you try to access GUI elements from a worker thread. You should notify any changes to the GUI thread via messages, and let the GUI thread update the GUI. Check http://www.flounder.com/workerthreads.htm

Comment: @MikMik That link is so full of uninformed opinion, that it's not even funny. I understand that it is posted a lot lately - that doesn't make any of the sections following *Worker threads and the GUI* right. There is nothing inherently wrong with having a GUI on a worker thread. There is nothing wrong with sending a `WM_GETTEXT` message to a control owned by a different thread either. There are lots of things that are in fact legal, even a window hierarchy spreading multiple threads. Please don't post that link again, and forget that it ever existed.

Comment: hmmm, thank you for all your post. Nevertheless I'm still not able to make head or tail of it. There seems to exist disagreement within community regarding this issue.

Comment: Please let me mention that the code I published is just an example to illustrate my general course of action. It doesn't make sense in terms of it functionality.

Comment: @GregPhil i have tested with and without this pointer it looks same.

Comment: @GregPhil But i have encountered some problem when using mfc controls in worker thread 1. when mfc main thread hangs, in this if worker thread try to access mfc controls worker thread may also hangs which may occurs very rare. 2. if oncancel event is called it will destroy all the controls, during this fraction of time if worker thread calls the mfc controls it leads to crash.

Answer (score 0):

Without going into too much details, here is how you should do it. I have't build, judged or modified your basic code, I have just addressed your threading part of question. You should be able to take it from here.

```
UINT CMyDlg::ControlThread(LPVOID pParam)
{
  HWND hWnd = (HWND) pParam;
  CString Text = "Hello";
  while(SomethingIsTrue) {
    bool Ret = SendMessage(HwND, VALIDATE_CONTROL,0,0 );
    if (!Ret) //Someone changed ControlEntry -> change it back
     SendMessage(CHANGE_EDIT_HELLO, &Text, 0);
  }
  AfxEndThread(0);
}
```